# How to calculate the optimal distribution of lines with different lengths into larger lines with fixed lengths

Tags: calculus

Background: DYI project with floorboards. Floorboard is sold in 3m pieces. I need lots of smaller cuts with different lengths.

Now I need a way to calculate the optimal distribution of floorboard-cuts per 3m floorboard unit, so the least material is wasted.

It's probably really simple, but my math knowledge is basically nonexistent.

Thanks! :)

Here's the data, if you're interested:

```
16x 800
9x  762
4x  210
2x  371
4x  800
4x  380
2x  698
8x  736
```

Comment: DYI = Do Yourself In? `:-)` I expect that you really want DIY.

Comment: Is the unit cm at your table ?

Comment: What do the numbers in your table mean? Does "$16$x $800$" mean you need sixteen pieces that are each $800$ centimeters long? You can't cut those from three-meter pieces. The nice thing about floorboards is you can use multiple pieces in line with each other. After cutting the last piece in the line to fit you can use the cut-off piece to start the next row, and so forth. You could try making a scale model of the boards and the floor to lay them on if you want to see how it works without cutting actual boards.

Comment: @DavidK:
Ah, sorry, no. It means 16 pieces of 800mm floorboard. Only the length is relevant, the width and depth is always the same (95x19, but completely irrelevant here).

Thing is, I go to the hardware store, take out the needed number of "raw" floorboards, and tell them exactly how to cut them. So I should have it all planned out in advance.

Comment: @callculus:
It's mm. quantity times length in mm.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott
Argh, yes. Yes, indeed. DIY it should be.

Comment: So you need $20\times 800 (=16\times 800+4\times 800)$ ?

Comment: Are you really interested in an answer ? I would only post an answer if you are, because it´s very time consuming.

Comment: There are so many ways this could go wrong, I hesitate to encourage it. As they say, "Measure twice, cut once." You may find after you start putting the floor down that some of your mm-precision measurements were not correct, and if the shop already cut the wood and it's too short, where does that leave you? Wasting wood is where it leaves you. Also keep in mind that each cut destroys some wood, maybe a couple of mm (but the exact amount depends on the saw). On the other hand, a "3 meter" board may actually be a bit longer than 3000 mm.

Comment: I would invest in a saw before undertaking a project like this.

Comment: Just to clarify: I use the floorboards for furniture building. And I'm rather adept at woodworking, actually. I even have the equipment, but hardly any space to use it in my new apartment. Also my favorite hardware store cuts quick, precise and for free. Okay, I tried to keep it as theoretical as possible because I feared getting tarred and feathered for asking DIY stuff on the math board, BUT.. here's the drawing: https://eet.li/ce2cf00.png and here's one of my earlier pieces, same style: https://eet.li/8b92359.png

Comment: Oh, and @callculus -- I thought there could be an easy way.. so, no. Don't bother. I'll just do it as I did it before, guessing and ending up with some extra wood. Doesn't matter as floorboards are ridiculously cheap. But thanks for the help :)